# drop hive external table after delete data,No way?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive external table.
first I delete the hdfs file use `hdfs dfs -rm -r /.../tableName` ,then I drop the table,Unfortunately,I can't drop the table!

Then I move the file from Trash to table Catalog,aka restore the file,but I also could not drop the table!

now,I can not create a new table ,nor drop the table,what can I do to drop the table ?

Comment: Do you see any error messages?

Comment: No,there is just no response when I try drop the table continously.

Comment: Do you have sentry enabled in your system?. If yes, check whether the group/role has access to drop the tables. Also, can you attach the DDL of the table and the steps that you are performing on it?.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly delete hdfs file from the hive shell may be it works for safely remove the data.

```
hive> dfs -rmr /user/hive/warehouse/database_name.db/table_name;
```

OR

```
hive> dfs -rm -r /user/hive/warehouse/database_name.db/table_name;
```

Then you can wipe it completely using DROP TABLE command.

Comment: you can get the path of data from hive shell
`hive> describe formatted database_name.table_name;`